# twilio from number required

Tags: php, twilio

trying to do the most basic function using twilio and i have come across a problem.  It wants a from number, even though I have supplied it.  Any thoughts?

```
<?php
require_once('Services/Twilio.php');

$twilioNumber = "someValidNumber";
$dest = "SomeValidDestination";

$AccountSid = "ValidSid";
$AuthToken = "ValidToken";

$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

try {
    $message = $client->account->messages->create(
    $twilioNumber,
    $dest,
    "Hello World!");

} catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

?>

results in:

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/sms/Services/Twilio.php on line 248
A 'From' phone number is required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the docs are a bit misleading.  change

```
account->messages->create
```

to

```
account->messages->sendMessage
```

and it works fine.